# Suitable reference for learning symplectic geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, self-learning, symplectic-geometry

I am interested in studying symplectic geometry by myself and I'm looking for a good text to use as a reference in the way.

I am a bit lost because I've found a lot of notes and books on the subject (like [these ones](http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~acannas/Books/lsg.pdf) which looks pretty nice, or [this set of notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/sympl.pdf) which look harder than the first ones to me) and I don't know if they are any good or if there is any canonical reference on the field.

If possible, I am looking for something with as many physical examples as possibles as I've already taken several courses on physics ranging from classical mechanics and thermodynamics to quantum field theory and particle physics.

In short, **I'm looking for a canonical reference for learning symplectic geometry with physical examples. Is there any?**

Comment: McDuff-Salamon is the canonical reference but has a single section on the relevance to physics.

Comment: @MikeMiller Do you mean "Introduction to Symplectic Topology" or "J-holomorphic Curves and Symplectic Topology"?

Comment: The introduction.

Comment: Guillemin & Sternberg’s _Symplectic Techniques In Physics_ might be the sort of thing you’re looking for.

Comment: I think Ana's ones which you have already found are the easiest place to start.